# authentication in between microservies in asp.net core

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, restful-authentication

Could some one tell me what is the best way to authenticate the request passed between micro-services and restrict the direct request to services from browsers

Comment: Microservices would generally auth with each other via client credentials, most likely, and you'd use a hybrid grant flow on the JavaScript/client side. Implementing that is far beyond the scope of Stack Overflow, but you'll likely want to look at something like IdentityServer or a hosted service like Auth0.

Answer (score 0):

It usually depends on the specific requirements of your app and services. In your case, one option is to use [Mutual authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_authentication).

In case you have a requirement where one of your microservices needs to be called by an authenticated user from the browser which in turn needs make another authenticated request to microservice, you can consider [On-Behalf-Of](https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/which-oauth-flow-to-use) flow (e.g. [Azure Active Directory On-Behalf-Of](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow))